# How to make email sending options

Tags: html

What i want to achieve is , when i click my contact us link a pop up should open which says "This link needs to be opened with an application". An below there should be options for opening the link using either gmail or outlook or yahoo.

Comment: Outlook is an application, GMail is a *web* application, and Yahoo! … is a company that does lots of things … perhaps you mean Yahoo! Mail? Either way, in most cases the correct way to handle this is to use a regular link and let the user's browser preferences handle the rest.

Comment: @Qutntin Yes i meant Yahoo! Mail..Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a hyperlink of type `<a href="mailto:your@emailadres.com"?subject=mysubject>Contact me</a>` then the webbrowser will open the link in the user's default email program.

You can't "force" a user to open a specific email application or webmail system and it isn't usefull either because every user has it's own default email (web)application.